# C# GUI with tabs

Tags: c#, user-interface

I want to make a WindowsFormApplication that has multiple tabs.

Like

For different options, like a "Settings" tab maybe an "About tab" 
etc.
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx), of course.  It should be in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways, but the one that first comes to mind would be to make your tabs manually, and switch out different panels. A panel can hold objects inside it, and when you hide it, everything inside it is hidden as well. You can stack panels and switch them out.